# I designed a circuit to receive multiple AC voltages at the input and constant voltage at the output, but I wonder if the circuit makes any sense

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, generator, ac-dc, step-down, step-up

[image]

I wonder if this circuit has any meaning and if it will work as I expect.

I would like to know before I build it, due to lack of time.

What I want from this circuit is to give motorcycle lamps the power that they need, but the problem is that the generator produces a wide range of voltages. Low voltage at engine idle and high voltage at acceleration. I would like this circuit to change AC to DC and give the lamps the correct voltage they need.

Comment: What circuit? I don't see one.

Comment: What's with all the arrows?

Comment: no, the arrows is caused by the program that i draw circuits in, they are just a lines

Comment: this is the circuit :                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqAvj.png

Comment: which lines join, which do not?  please use one of the normal conventions for joining and crossing lines.  please explain how the circuit is supposed to work,

Comment: Any line you see that meets another line is connected to it, and forget the arrows,

Comment: the work of the circuit is the switching between 4 triac when two triac turn on the others triac while not

Comment: _"I **designed** a circuit..."_ - then you should be able to tell us how it is supposed to work. Can you?

Comment: waw, man relax, i said i designed because i created it from my mind like all circuit who i made it, It is not cloned from somewhere, this all

Comment: A regulator needs a reference. I don't see what would make the output 24VDC instead of some other voltage. How does it know if the output is too high or too low? If you needed 12VDC instead of 24VDC, what component values would need to change?

Comment: I fail to see how this is intended to work. Can you explain why you designed it the way you did?

Comment: I'm not fully up to speed on motorcycle electrical systems, but don't they have a voltage regulator of some kind as in cars?  Separate from that, either a clipper or a hysteretic regulator is less complicated.

Comment: Motorcycle voltage regulators are often crude devices that use a TRIAC to short across the alternator **AC** output when it rises above a reference voltage. They rely on the alternator's high leakage inductance and rising frequency with voltage to limit shunt current. The output waveform is similar to a trailing edge light dimmer but with variable frequency, only suitable for powering incandescent bulbs.

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, this circuit confuses the hell out of me, and it looks like someone tried to invent the synchronous full-bridge rectifier (not that you'd need that in this use case) but then stopped halfway.

It's also not clear what would lead to voltage regulation.

So, since you yourself say you didn't properly design this, let's not waste too much time on understanding how something is supposed to work that probably doesn't work.

Instead, honestly, this calls for a simple half-bridge diode-based rectifier with a step-down switch-mode converter. Depending on whether you need isolation, that might be a simple buck or a more complex flyback converter.

Financially, building this yourself makes no sense. Buy a ready-made ac/dc module with appropriate input range. Or, alternatively, go to any smps ic manufacturer website (I personally like TI.com) and check out their power supply design tools instead of guess-dreaming a schematic